# Multiple Requests on ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, asihttprequest

I need to download three different sets of data from three different URLs. I decided to use ASIHTTPRequest. Two of the URLs are JSON feeds which I need to parse and one of them is a .txt file online that I need to store locally.

Now the example that is on ASIHTTPRequest's website for an asynchronous request shows the following:

```
- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender {
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

To pass multiple URLs, I can call "request" on three different URLs. But I am not sure how I would handle them in the `requestFinished` method. The documentation shows it as:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
   // Use when fetching text data
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

   // Use when fetching binary data
   NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
}
```

How would this method differentiate between different requests, so that I can handle it differently?

Thank you,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can differentiate between different requests by

- setting the userInfo dictionary of the request
- setting the didFinishSelector (and didFailSelector etc.) to different methods
- using different classes as delegate
- using blocks
- using the request's tag property
- subclass ASIHTTPRequest and override override requestFinished: and failWithError: (only recommended for complex situations)

Comment: You can also use request.tag in the most recent versions.

Comment: I highly recommend using blocks. Your code will be cleaner, and easy to follow.

Comment: @Nayefc read the blocks programming guide first http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks

Answer (score 3):

You just need two snippets of code. One to 'tag' your url:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"identifierX", @"typeOfRequest",nil]];
```

and another one to identify it:

```
if ([[[request userInfo] valueForKey:@"typeOfRequest"] isEqualToString:@"identifierX"]){
        // Do here whatever you need to do for the url associated with identifierX
    }
```

and that should be it!

Answer (score 1):

you can set the Username and tag of req.

this is the example of imageview. req.

```
UIImageView *imgV=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416)];

    ASIHTTPRequest *req=[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.arr objectAtIndex:i]]];
    [req setUsername:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i]];
    [req setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:imgV,@"imgV",nil]];
    [req setDelegate:self];
    [req startAsynchronous];
    [imgV setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    [imgV setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [imgV setTag:kTagImageViewInScrollView];
    [scr2 addSubview:imgV];
    [scr2 setDelegate:self];
    [imgV release]; imgV=nil;
```

and in requestFinished

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    [(UIImageView*)[[request userInfo] valueForKey:@"imgV"] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[request responseData]]];   

}
```

Comment: This answer contains the proper response, but should be trimmed a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the originalURL property of ASIHTTPRequest if you have different URLS.

Or you can use [request hash] to get the NSObject hash for each object and check that later.