# Set different callback with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, asihttprequest

For an app i'm currently making i use the ASIHTTPRequest API to do my communication:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://testService.com"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request appendPostData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:20.0f];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

NSData * postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionnary2 options:0 error:nil];

[request setPostLength:[postData length]];

[request appendPostData:postData];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

i already have working calls in place but they both go to the same callback method : 
`- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request`

I want each call to have it's own callback method since i call one call from the callback method of the other. How can i do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571947/multiple-requests-on-asihttprequest   maybe it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this kind for situation i would always prefer to use Blocks for call backs.

Check this [link](http://maniacdev.com/2010/07/blocks-an-interesting-objective-c-addition-in-ios-4/) for block implementation methods and design,